# String.contains always appears false

Tags: java, string, contains

```
public final void nameErrorLoop () {
    while (error) {
        System.out.println("Enter the employee's name.");
        setName(kb.next()); 
        if (name.contains("[A-Za-z]")) {
            error = false; 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The name can only contain letters.");
        }
    }
    error = true; 
}
```

Despite a similar setup working in a different method, this method becomes stuck in a constant loop because the if statement is always false.  I've tried `.matches()`, and nothing that I found on the Interent has helped so far.  Any ideas why?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit: I just noticed as I was finishing the project, that trying to print 'name' later only shows the first name, and the last is never printed.  Is there any way I can get the 'name' string to include both?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`String.contains` doesn't use regular expressions - it just checks whether one string contains another, in the way that "foobar" contains "oob".

It sounds like you want to check that `name` *only* contains letters, in which case you should be checking something like:

```
if (name.matches("^[A-Za-z]+$"))
```

The `+` (instead of `*`) will check that it's non-empty; the `^` and `$` will check that there's nothing other than the letters.

If you expect it to be a full name, however, you may well want to allow spaces, hyphens and apostrophes:

```
if (name.matches("^[-' A-Za-z]+$"))
```

Also consider accented characters - and punctuation from other languages.

Comment: Also, in the U.S at least, some places have lax [laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law) regarding abusive naming of children and allow numbers and other weirdness: "...some states ban the use of numerals or pictograms. A few states ban the use of obscenity. There are also a few states, Kentucky for instance, that have no naming laws whatsoever."

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for the thorough explanation.  I'll mark it as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Luckily for me this is just for a homework assignment.  I don't have to worry about state laws, just general naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. .contains() is not what you think. It does exact String matching.

```
    "anything".contains("something that's not a regular expression");
```

Either use this

```
Pattern p2=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");//call only once
p2.matcher(txt).find();//call in loop
```

or this:

```
    for(char ch: "something".toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(ch)){

    }
}
```